# EF 6 in C# app - Unable to update a table-valued UDF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF 6 and I have a table-valued UDF in my .edmx. However, after making a change to the UDF in SQL Server, and coming back to EF and updating the model from the database, the reference to the UDF is never updated. I have to manually delete all references to the UDF and reimport, and then it's fine. Is this a bug, or something wrong I'm doing?

Comment: What is a UDF? Can you show us some code and the section of the EDMX?

Comment: A UDF is a SQL Server user-defined function. A Table-valued UDF is a user-defined function that returns a table.

Comment: I am facing the same issue now. Did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: No I never did. I always had to remove the references and re-add.